# How can I set the title of the Delete view with AOR?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I see the Delete component takes a Title prop but how would one pass such prop to it for a given resource?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good example in the demo source code: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/visitors/index.js#L116